# PHP Crushing/Explode text

Tags: php

I have a one input that is used for a  "Name, Surname and Family name". But I want if user enter more than 3 names, all after 3(4,5,6...) to be like family. But if you submit 2 names the Family name must be "0".

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="getNames.php">
    Names: <input type="text" name="names" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php

$names = $_POST['names'];

// some action here to get names

$firstName = ""; // Get first name
$surName = ""; // Get Sur name
$familyName = ""; // Get family name

?>
```

I will be very glad if someone help me. Thanks!

Comment: how are you counting names, separating with spaces ?

Comment: @kamalpal Yes, but space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will output an array of familly, if an input is missing, it will be replaced with a 0.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$_POST['names'] = 'sofiene, totose, tata, titi';
$names = explode(',', $_POST['names']);
$familly = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i+=3) {
    $familly[$i] = [
        'firstName' => (isset($names[$i])) ? $names[$i] : 0,
        'surName' => (isset($names[$i + 1])) ? $names[$i + 1] : 0,
        'familyName' => (isset($names[$i + 2])) ? $names[$i + 2] : 0
    ];
}
var_dump($familly);
?>
```

[EvalIn](https://eval.in/574931)

Comment: Well done, but "Notice: Undefined variable: key in".

Comment: Done :), don't forget to mark the answer as solved is the code is good pls sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` with a space, and use `array_filter` on that to remove blanks, as user may input two spaces.

There after you can use `array_shift` which return you a value from top of an array.

and later check if array isn't empty, then use `implode` with spaces otherwise set `$familyName` to `0`

```
<?php
$names = 'John Doe';
$arrNames = array_filter(explode(' ', $names));

echo $firstName = array_shift($arrNames) . PHP_EOL;
echo $surName = array_shift($arrNames) . PHP_EOL;
echo $familyName = empty($arrNames) ? '0' : implode(' ', $arrNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

This what your looking for?

```
$_POST['names'] = '   Arthur     Ignatius       Conan  Doyle   ';

$names = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['names']));

$parts = explode(' ',$names , 3);

list($firstNamm, $surName, $familyName) =  array_replace(array_fill(0,3,''), $parts  );
```

Explanation,

`preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['names'])` is used to reduce multiple spaces down to a single whitespace.

from

```
'   Arthur     Ignatius       Conan  Doyle   '
```

to

```
' Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle '
```

[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is used to remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, you can provide a second argument if you wish to remove other characters.

which now gives us

```
'Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle'
```

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) splits a string into an array when given a delimiter (" "), the 3rd arguments let you set the maximum number of parts to split the string into.

as the string may not have 3 parts its possible that an empty array is returned. 
`array_fill(0,3,'')` creates an array with three elements all set to an empty string. 
`array_replace(array_fill(0,3,''), $parts  );` returns the array but with values replaced with any values provided by the `$parts` array.

This array is passed to the `list` construct which populates a list of variables with the values of each array element.